# ReplaceWith вставляет HTML элемент как текст

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Пытаюсь изменить один DOM элемент, на другой. При этом, обращаюсь к нему просто как к тексту, передавая параметр this из функции:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addToCart('{{ $meal->id }}', this)">

...


        let addToCart = (id, caller) => {
            caller.replaceWith("<h1>helloworld</h1>");
        }
```

По итогу, функция заменяет кнопку, без взаимодействия с тегами, то есть на выходе я получаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я НЕ МОГУ обратиться к элементу иначе, потому что кнопки находятся в Blade-овском цикле, и уникальный идентификатор им не присвоишь.

Answer (score 1):

1. Создаете нужный элемент через `document.createElement`;
2. Задаете ему все, что необходимо;
3. Делаете `replaceWith`, но в него передаете созданный элемент, а не строку.

Пример на основе вашего:

```js
let addToCart = (id, caller) => {
    let newElem = document.createElement('h1');
    newElem.innerText = 'helloWorld!';
    caller.replaceWith(newElem);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addToCart('{{ $meal->id }}', this)">abc</button>
```